# Prerequisites for App Engine development are missing

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I just installed Google App Engine and it's telling me that the SDK and Python are not installed.  I just ran the SDK installer so I would think that that is okay, but I KNOW I have Python 2.7 installed as I use it on a daily basis.

It does say that if the items are installed I can edit the preferences to point App Engine to the right path using Edit>Preferences.  However whenever I kick off the App Launcher it simply stops responding after the first error message and I can never change anything.  Any potential solutions to this problem are greatly appreciated

Comment: I had similar trouble in one machine. launcher/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log displays Python error messages, and `WindowsError: [Error 64] The specified network name is no longer available: 'Q:\\/Google` (forgotten internal dependency??). Couldn't make the launcher work in that machine, but appcfg.py and dev_appserver.py still work just file if you put the SDK in your path, so it doesn't really matter that much if you are comfortable with the command line.

Comment: @KallePokki if you put that in a question I'll give you the answer, meant to respond to this long ago, just slipped through the cracks

Answer (score 0):

Confirm directories under Preferences of Google App Engine.

App Engine SDK: C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine

Python Path: C:\Users\Noman Raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

[image]